# Nixing screen output with log4j

Tags: log4j

One of the irritating things with log4j is that it always wants to dump stuff to the screen.  I don't need that if I'm logging to a file.  I'm sure it's in how I set up the log4j.properties file.  Getting all of this configuration stuff ironed out is frustrating!  :-)

For a program I'm currently calling Balancer, this is how I'm doing my logger initialization.  Perhaps it is wrong or something.

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Balancer.class);
```

A partial dump of my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=fatal, stdout
log4j.logger.Balancer=fatal, rollingLog

# I still don't understand how category stuff works yet
log4j.category.Balancer=info, BalancerLog

#### First appender writes to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

#### Second appender writes to a file
# Control the maximum log file size
# Archive log files (ten backups here)
log4j.appender.rollingLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingLog.File=default.log
log4j.appender.rollingLog.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.rollingLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.rollingLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.BalancerLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.BalancerLog.File=Balancer.log
log4j.appender.BalancerLog.MaxFileSize=100000KB
log4j.appender.BalancerLog.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.BalancerLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.BalancerLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

I get how the rootLogger sends stuff to the stdout appender.  Is there a /dev/null appender?  You have to have at least one appender.

Anyway, if nothing else, my basic work-around now is to send screen output to /dev/null.  BTW, my Java programs run in a scheduled batch environment (no GUI).  Having to clean up spooled files (yes this is on an AS/400) is a bit of a pain, although that can be automated as well.

Comment: What result are you aiming for?  Do you want `Balancer` messages to go only to the `Balancer.log` file or do you want fatal-level `Balancer` messages to go also to the `default.log`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a /dev/null appender?

Yes.

```
log4j.appender.devnull=org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender
log4j.rootLogger=fatal, devnull
```

I'm not sure where you got `log4j.category.*` from but it's not something I've seen before, I would stick to just using `appender` and `logger`.

```
log4j.logger.Balancer=fatal, rollingLog, BalancerLog
```

would send `fatal` level messages for the logger named `Balancer` (with no package prefix) to both the rollingLog and BalancerLog appenders.  If you change the logger level to `info`

```
log4j.logger.Balancer=info, rollingLog, BalancerLog
```

then it would send messages of level `info` and above to both appenders.  You can't restrict it so that BalancerLog gets `info` and above but rollingLog gets only `fatal` messages *on a per-logger basis*, but you can set a threshold on the rollingLog appender so that it only records `fatal` messages (regardless of the logger they came from)

```
log4j.appender.rollingLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingLog.Threshold=fatal
log4j.appender.rollingLog.File=default.log
# other parameters as before
```